# Website working in Chrome / Firefox but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I've recently put up a new website at [www.matmetzner.co.uk](http://www.matmetzner.co.uk) , it was designed with `Chrome` as my default browser, and seems to work fine in Firefox too, but `IE` gives me just the background image. I'm a games designer by trade and know a little web design, but I'm certainly no expert in this area as you can probably tell.

Can anyone see anything in my source code that might be causing it?

Sorry the question is a little vague but because none of it works, it's difficult to see the point of the break and therefore know which specific bit to try and fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some code for us to look at. We can't guess what may be the problem.

Comment: I like your My Skills tab :) especially html :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To start with I would add below to your head section-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

Which might fix some problems. I'm not going to go into details about what this meta tag does. Please have a look at [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started) or google it. Also use a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to bring all the browser defaults to a standard.

Then address individual differences and treat them for IE. Also remember to use [conditional styles sheets](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) (only if things started getting a bit difficult). Last but not the least remember [a website doesn't need to look same in all the browsers](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/) as long as it doesn't compromise the usability and purpose of the website.

Hope this helps

Comment: Excellent, yeah that meta tag seems to have sorted it, I'll keep that one handy for future use. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You also don't close your style tag

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--                                      < - BEGIN OF COMMENT
body {
    background-image: url(img/grass.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}


#website {
    position:absolute;
    width:211px;
    height:24;
    z-index:1;
    left: 799px;
    top: 3px;
}
.style1 {color: #FFFFFF}
</style>                                   < - COMMENT NEVER ENDED, SO TAG NOT READ?
```

From here IE is actually assuming it is still reading your style tags. Even though you are already presenting content.

Comment: Not sure why that comment open is there, but the body background image is loading within it so assume it's being read, I'll try that now though, thanks